# Rails, ActiveRecord: has_one where column names match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, tiny-tds

I have an association where a `project has_many steps` and I want to find the "current" `step` for the `project`.  The `project` table stores a `current_step` value, which is the `step.name` for the current `step`.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  # attributes: step_name:string

  has_many :steps
  has_one :current_step, -> { where("steps.name = projects.step_name") }, class_name: "Step"
end

class Step < ApplicationRecord
  # attributes: project_id:integer, name:string

  belongs_to :project
end
```

I'm trying to set it up as an ActiveRecord association, so I can optimize loading the `current_step` with the `project` and avoid `n+1` issues.

However, I keep getting the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: The multi-part identifier "projects.step_name" could not be bound.
```

I did some looking on SO and saw others have encountered this TinyTds error, but I'm not entirely sure what it means or how it relates to my particular situation.

How do I select the `current_step` such that it can efficiently be included to avoid `n+1`?

Comment: try adding `.first` in your `where`

Comment: Try defining the `has_one` relationship with something like `has_one :current_step, -> { joins(:steps).where("steps.name = ?", step_name) }, class_name: "Step"`

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have a `has_one` association, you have a special member of the `has_many` so I'd express it that way. An extension method on the `steps` association will let you do that:

```
has_many :steps do
  def current
    project = proxy_association.owner
    find_by(name: project.step_name)
  end
end
```

The `proxy_association` that ActiveRecord sets up for associations lets you backtrack up to the containing `project` as `proxy_association.owner`. The `find_by` inside the extension method will be scoped to the association.

Then you can say things like:

```
project.steps.current
```

to get what you're expecting your `has_one` to do.

Comment: That's interesting.  Does that allow me to do `Project.includes(:current)`?  I need to display a collection of `project` records with some data from their current `step` on a page and want to avoid `n+1` issues.

Comment: You could add a scope to join to the steps with a WHERE clause to grab the appropriate row. Or try including a JOIN in your `has_one` to make both tables visible.